# import @Openzeppelin/contrancts string literal (path) error

Tags: web3js, openzeppelin

I am new at web3 and I am trying to fix this problem. it is about openzeppelin/contracts import error "Expected string literal (path), "*" or alias list." and this is the error definition. I install openzeppelin/contracts but this problem was never solved. how can I fix it?

I am new at web[enter image description here][1]3 and I am trying to fix this problem. it is about openzeppelin/contracts import error "Expected string literal (path), "*" or alias list." and this is the error definition. I install openzeppelin/contracts but this problem was never solved. how can I fix it?

```js
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import  '@openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC721\ERC721.sol';
import  '@openzeppelin\contracts\access\Ownable.sol';


contract safakNft is ERC721,Ownable{
    uint256 public mintPrices; 
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    uint256 public maxSupply;
    uint256 public maxPerWallet;
    bool public isPublicMintEnabled;
    string internal baseTokenUri;
    address payable public withdrawWallet;
    mapping(address =>uint256) public walletMints;
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the "@openzeppelin" folder and paste it inside the "contracts" folder, then import it ( import "./@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";). Just remember to add it to the gitIgnore file (it should be dark blue after you done it).